# Adding onClick to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that adds table rows when a button is clicked.

when adding rows, in one of the cells it uses:

```
var linkCell = row.insertCell(1);
var elLink = document.createElement('a');
var href='http://www.domain.co.uk/';
elLink.href = href;
elLink.innerHTML = 'Choose Product '+i;
linkCell.appendChild(elLink);
```

to add a HTML a href to each row but I want to be able to used `onClick` rather than a `href`

I have tried:

```
var linkCell = row.insertCell(1);
var elLink = document.createElement('a');
var href='javascript:void(0);';
var onClick=window.open('/admin/chooseproduct.php?c='+i,'Popup','width=550,height=500,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,');
elLink.href = href;
elLink.innerHTML = 'Choose Product '+i;
linkCell.appendChild(elLink);
```

but that does not open the popup window as it should - how can I do this?

Comment: You don't appear to actually assign the onClick variable to anything. Try `elLink.onclick = onClick;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two problems:

First, you are not every applying the `onclick` method to the element: you are only defining it as a variable.

```
var onClick = ...     // won't work
elLink.onclick = ...  // will work
```

Second, you are not creating an `onclick` handler with the code you're writing. `onClick = window.open(...)` doesn't say "open a window when the element is clicked". Rather it says "open a window right now, and set `onClick` to be a reference to that window".

You need to create a new function. This function will be assigned as the event handler and only executed when the link is clicked. It will itself call `window.open`.

```
elLink.onclick = function() {
    window.open('/admin/chooseproduct.php?c='+i,'Popup','width=550,height=500,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
var linkCell = row.insertCell(1);
        var elLink = document.createElement('a');
        var href='javascript:void(0);';
        elLink.href = href;
        elLink.innerHTML = 'Choose Product '+i;
        linkCell.appendChild(elLink);
        elLink.onclick= function() {
        window.open('/admin/chooseproduct.php?
       c='+i,'Popup','width=550,height=500,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,'); //Attach event here
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Been using jQuery for too long. But still I suppose you need to assign the  `onClick` function you defined to the `elLink` element for it to trigger. At present, that does not seem to be happening.